# jQuery datepicker: Convert select dropdown into ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am using the  jquery-ui datepicker component however the `month` and `year` dropdowns are `select` tags.

I need to style them in ways that are not possible with select elements so I would like to convert them to `ul` elements.

Any help would be appreciated - here is a starter jsFiddle with the jquery-ui datepicker https://jsfiddle.net/GeekOnGadgets/wra3pcsv/

Comment: Why you've not used `ui-datepicker-year` & `ui-datepicker-month` class to apply style?

Comment: Does not work, need hover of the select in different colour and other requirement, which is stuff to change with select.

Comment: I add :
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{
   background: #ffff00;
 }
 .ui-state-default:hover, .ui-widget-content:hover .ui-state-default:hover, .ui-widget-header:hover .ui-state-default:hover{
   background: #ff0000;
 }
to your css and its work.
I think you need call appropriate class as this calendar declare. 
Thanks

Comment: @AmranurRahman I think you misunderstood the question. I want to change the dropdown.

Comment: Cleaned up grammar and explained that the styles required cannot be done to a select as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: So instead of selects you want them replaced with lists? How would that look?

Comment: On what grounds you are down voting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code may help you. You can see the result in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/wra3pcsv/7/).

```
// Replace a select element by a ul element
var convertToList = function (inst, className) {
    var $selectElement = inst.dpDiv.find('.' + className);
    var $listElement = $('<ul class="{0} dateList"></ul>'.replace('{0}', className + '-list')).appendTo($selectElement.parent());
    $selectElement.children(' option').each(function () {
        // Replace each option of the select element by a li element
        $listElement.append('<li class="dateListItem" value="{0}">{1}</li>'.replace('{0}', $(this).val()).replace('{1}', $(this).text()));
    });
    $listElement.find('.dateListItem').click(function () {
        // When an item is clicked, set the corresponding value in
        // the original select element and trigger the change event
        $selectElement.val($(this).val());
        $selectElement.change();
    }).each(function () {
        // Add the selectedValue class to the selected item
        if ($(this).val() == $selectElement.val()) {
            $(this).addClass('selectedValue');
        }
    });
};

// Replace the month and year select elements
var convertToDatePickerWithLists = function (inst) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        inst.dpDiv.addClass('datePickerWithLists');
        convertToList(inst, 'ui-datepicker-month');
        convertToList(inst, 'ui-datepicker-year');
    }, 0);
};

// Associate the datepicker to the text input element
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        // Modify the datepicker when it is initially displayed
        convertToDatePickerWithLists(inst);
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
        // Modify the datepicker every time the month/year is changed
        convertToDatePickerWithLists(inst);
    }
});
```

Here are the CSS styles for the various classes:

```
.datePickerWithLists .ui-datepicker-year,
.datePickerWithLists .ui-datepicker-month
{
    display: none; /* Hide the original select elements */
}

.datePickerWithLists .ui-datepicker-header
{
    height: 20em;
    background: #D0D0D0;
}

.dateList
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
}

.dateListItem
{
    line-height: 1.4em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dateListItem.selectedValue
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

**UPDATE**

After discussing the specific needs of GeekOnGadgets, the code and style has been adapted as shown in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/wra3pcsv/15/).

Comment: thanks for your answer :). I tried to made change what you did but got stuck at selecting month and year and then closing dropdown. Tried few things but nothing. Do you mind taking a look at the fiddle i am working on? Hope to get some help with it `https://jsfiddle.net/GeekOnGadgets/wra3pcsv/12/`

Comment: I am trying to figure out what result you want to get. Do you simply want two dropdown lists? Or a single dropdown list which includes the month and year?

Comment: OK, I am working on it. By the way, Dekel's solution is very close to what you want, no?

Comment: You can find an updated version of the jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/wra3pcsv/14/. I fixed the height of the datepicker header to avoid excessive flicker. When I test in VS2015 with jquery 3.1.0, the calendar does not go beyond December 2016 (which it does in the jsfiddle). You may consider setting the `z-index` for the lists, to avoid some other glitches.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are one genius programmer. The reason it does not go beyond 2016 is because `yearRange: '-80:+0'`. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I added a remark about the `z-index` in my last comment. You may notice that some items in the lists are not easily selectable. Setting `z-index: 1` for the ul lists seems to solve that problem.

Comment: Yes I saw that, thanks. Will make changes as necessary :)

Comment: currently solution has the toggle, so if year and month both clicked, both would show. Can you please guide me what method to use, so i can hide month or year if clicked outside of their respective dropdown. I tried using `.show` and `.hide`. any suggestions ?

Comment: UPDATE: found a bug - if you input a date for eg `10/28/1993` the month and year disappears. Trying to figure out what function is getting called.

Comment: For the problem where both lists are shown, I updated [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/wra3pcsv/16/). Adding `$('.dateListItem').not($currentList).hide();` seems to work.

Comment: I tried different things for input date bug, but nothing seems to fix it. Did you had a chance to look at it ?

Comment: I tried a few things also, without much success. The only workaround that I found was to make the text box read-only. I don't know if that is an option for you. Otherwise, it will take more time and effort to find a better solution.

Comment: unfortunately, can't make it ready only. even @Dekel solution breaks when input box is used.

Comment: The solution could be to redefine the `_updateDatepicker` method of the datepicker, to include a call to our function in it. I did not find the correct way to do it yet (and I am a little busy tonight, I must admit).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123743/discussion-between-geekongadgets-and-connorsfan).

Answer (score 5):

This solution is mostly based on the solution by @ConnorsFan (you got a voteup from me for your solution), however if you want to have a solution based on the jQuery ui's `selectmenu` (so you can style everything based on jQuery ui's themes) you can use this code:

```
const fullMonthNames = ['Janurary', 'Februbary', 'March', 
    'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
    'September', 'October', 'Novermber', 'December'];

function updateToSelectMenu() {
    $('.ui-datepicker-title select').selectmenu({
        select: function(e) {
        $(this).trigger('change');
        updateToSelectMenu();
        }
    })
    $('.ui-datepicker-title').append($('.ui-selectmenu-menu'));
}

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: this.todayButton,
    yearRange: '-80:+0',
    monthNamesShort: fullMonthNames,
    beforeShow: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            updateToSelectMenu()
        }, 0);
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            updateToSelectMenu()
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

> The `selectmenu` was added in jQuery ui v1.11 so make sure you use the correct version.

Here is a working sample:

```js
const fullMonthNames = ['Janurary', 'Februbary', 'March', 
            'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
                        'September', 'October', 'Novermber', 'December'];
                        
function updateToSelectMenu() {
 $('.ui-datepicker-title select').selectmenu({
    select: function(e) {
      $(this).trigger('change');
      updateToSelectMenu();
    }
  })
  $('.ui-datepicker-title').append($('.ui-selectmenu-menu'));
}
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   showButtonPanel: this.todayButton,
   yearRange: '-80:+0',
   monthNamesShort: fullMonthNames,
   beforeShow: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
     updateToSelectMenu()
    }, 0);
   },
   onChangeMonthYear: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
     updateToSelectMenu()
    }, 0);
   }
 });
```

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.ui-datepicker-month, .ui-datepicker-year {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: none;
}

#ui-datepicker-div .ui-selectmenu-menu, #ui-datepicker-div .ui-selectmenu-button{
  width: 29%;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.ui-menu { 
  max-height: 420px !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: Very nice solution!